# breadth-first option in the Linux `find' utility?

Tags: linux, find

Is there any breadth-first/depth-first option in the Linux `find' utility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to find, even GNU find. You can postprocess the output of `find` to sort by number of slashes, for example with Perl:

```
find ... | perl -e 'print sort {$a=~s!/!/! <=> $b=~s!/!/!} <>'
```

- `<>` is the list of all input lines;
- `$a =~ s!/!/!g` is the number of slashes in `$a`, which we use as the sort criterion.

If you can use zsh:

```
echo **/*(oe\''REPLY=${REPLY//[^\/]}'\')
```

- `**/*` lists all files in the current directory and subdirectories.
- The stuff inside the parentheses is a glob qualifier.
- The glob qualifier `oe` controls the order in which matches are returned: they are sorted by the value of `REPLY` after running the code here in quotes for each match with `REPLY` initially set to the matched path.
- Said code transforms `$REPLY` to delete everything except slashes. So the result consists of everything at depth 1 (empty resulting `$REPLY`), then everything at depth 2 (`$REPLY` ends up to be `/`), depth 3 (`//`), etc.

Comment: The sort post process is very interesting, however, sort needs the find to be completed, and you won't have chance to control break.

Answer (score 3):

Nope

Go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539583/how-do-i-recursively-list-all-directories-at-a-location-breadth-first) on SO for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that you can.  It involves grep and such and a loop, but I find it works very well, specifically for your case about the find not needing to be completed.

It is more resource intensive because of:

- Lots of forking
- Lots of finds
- Each directory before the current depth is hit by find as many times as there is total depth to the file structure (this shouldn't be a problem if you have practically any amount of ram...)

This is good because:

- It uses bash and basic gnu tools
- It can be broken whenever you want (like you see what you were looking for fly by)
- It works per line and not per find, so subsequent commands don't have to wait for a find and a sort
- It works based on the actual file system separation, so if you have a directory with a slash in it, it won't be listed deeper than it is; if you have a different path separator configured, you still are fine.

```
#!/bin/bash 
depth=0

while find -mindepth $depth -maxdepth $depth | grep '.'
do
    depth=$((depth + 1))
done
```

You can also fit it onto one line fairly(?) easily:

```
depth=0; while find -mindepth $depth -maxdepth $depth | grep --color=never '.'; do depth=$((depth + 1)); done
```

But I prefer small scripts over typing...

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/23948137/1865272

```
#!/bin/bash

queue="$1"
shift

while [ -n "$queue" ]
do
    echo "$queue" | xargs -I'{}' find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 $*
    queue=`echo "$queue" | xargs -I'{}' find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`
done
```

From Jethro Yu https://stackoverflow.com/users/542730/jethro-yu